# Generating a heatmap with the twitter search term using cartodb api

Tags: carto, heat-map, twitter

I have a search box in my UI and a div for displaying maps.if i enter any term in the search box, say for example (chennai rain) does cartodb has any api or sample codes to generate a heatmap for that particular search term in the map div. Could any of you explain briefly how this functionality could be done using cartodb api?I have seen the possibility of generating geotagged maps using cartodb.
[image]

Comment: I may not be understanding what you are asking, but there are many sites about bringing twitter data into cartodb.  Example: http://blog.cartodb.com/twitter-maps/

Comment: My Snapshot would make you clear. If i enter a term in the search box, It should generate a heat map for that search term.Is there any specific api in cartodb to do this?

Comment: Do you have the Twitter Maps extension for CartoDB? It appears that CartoDB reads from the Twitter API and produces a map similar to what you are looking for.

Comment: Well i have installed cartodb locally in my ubuntu VM.I am curious to know by default it has the twitter maps extension or should we wana do any configuration for using it in my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CartoDB does allow to import data from Twitter from the CartoDB Editor, but it doesn't offer any API to do it externally from your end, so you cannot trigger the creation of Twitter data through CartoDB by using your own app.

You could perform that kind of filtering if you had already get from Twitter data the terms that you are going to filter by: you would just need to apply an SQL query to your layer and set there the table in which the data lives and how you want to get it.

Another approach, although probably is not useful at all for an application like the one you are showing, is to connect by yourself to the Twitter API, retrieve the information in a format compatible with CartoDB, import it to CartoDB (check the Import API [here](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/import-api/)) and then load a layer in your map with this new information. Assuming that this process would take several minutes, don't take this information as a recommendation for your question, but as "something feasible". If, for example, you are building a tool to generate some reports and this is not time sensitive this approach would make sense.

Comment: Thanks a lot iriberri for the response. By any chance, will there a update to use twitter search API in external application in cartodb?